# Source control for multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, sourcegear-vault

I've worked with SourceGear Vault for sometime for source control but I've run into a problem - which is going to be all the more common.

I have a visual studio solutions that looks like so:

```
-Main solution
      - Web App Project
      - Shared Class Library 1
      - Shared Class Library 2
```

The problem is that I can only bind the solution to one repository, however the class libraries are shared, they need to be used by multiple solutions.

Is there a source control solution that anyone knows of that will allow for a solution to contain multiple projects, all bound to different repositories?

Thanks in advance
Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the shared libraries separately and reference the assemblies. The building of the libraries can be automated (e.g. using Continuous Integration), so that this is an easy and efficient solution.

Comment: I had considered that as an option - but that means I wont be able to debug the class libraries, doesnt it?

Comment: If you have PDB files and the source is available, then you can also step into the libraries, no problem there. And an additional benefit is that you'll have faster build times ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A solution may be using [SubVersion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and the svn-externals.

You can integrate it in Visual Studio via [VisualSVN plugin](http://www.visualsvn.com/) (you must purchase it). 
If you want purchase it, you can use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)